# multer.memoryStorage() is returning req.file as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am having an issue where when using `multer.memoryStorage`, it is returning `req.file` as undefined. I can successfully use `multer.diskStorage` and save my files in a backend directory. So I do know my frontend is sending the `formData` as expected.

Here is my client side code responsible for sending the `formData`:

```
  filesUpload = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    const { files } = this.state;
    const filesKey = Object.keys(files);

    filesKey.forEach(key => {
      data.append('file', files[key]);
    });

    const axiosConfig = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    };

    axios.post('/v1/upload/files', axiosConfig, data, {}).then(res => {
      console.log(res.statusText);
    });
  };
```

Here is the Express server side code. This controller is hit when `'/v1/upload/files'` is called:

```
//Multer Engine
const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, '');
  }
});

const multipleUpload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');

exports.s3Upload = (req, res) => {
  multipleUpload(req, res, err => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send(req.file) //req.file is always undefined
  });
};
```

I am confused because as I said above, `multer.diskStorage` works for me just fine. I think I am missing a big piece to using `memoryStorage`. I will eventually be sending files handled with `multer` to an AWS S3 bucket if that makes a difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, is all I have to say.

```
const axiosConfig = {
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
};

axios.post('/v1/upload/files', data, axiosConfig).then(res => {
  console.log(res.statusText);
});
```

I had an empty object being passed into the Axios parameters in the original code.......

```
axios.post('/v1/upload/files', axiosConfig, data, {EMPTY}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.statusText);
});
```